# nvim change mapleader for filetype

Tags: neovim

I would like to change the global mapleader for a specific filetype in neovim, but I am unsucessful...

This is what I have setup:

```
vim.g.mapleader = " "
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>pv", vim.cmd.Ex)

vim.keymap.set("n", "n", "nzz")
vim.keymap.set("n", "N", "Nzz")
vim.keymap.set("v","<Tab>", ">gv")
vim.keymap.set("v","<S-Tab>", "<gv")
vim.keymap.set("n", "za", "zA")
vim.keymap.set("v", "<leader>y", '"+y')
vim.keymap.set("v", "<leader>p", '"+p')
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>s", [[:%s/\<<C-r><C-w>\>/<C-r><C-w>/gI<Left><Left><Left>]])
vim.keymap.set("x", "<leader>p", [["_dP]])
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('TextYankPost', {
    group = yank_group,
    pattern = '*',
    callback = function()
        vim.highlight.on_yank({
            higroup = 'IncSearch',
            timeout = 100,
        })
    end,
})

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"FileType"}, {
    pattern = "r",
    callback = function()
    vim.g.mapleader = "\\"
    vim.keymap.set("n", "<Space>", "<Plug>RDSendLine")
    vim.keymap.set("v", "<Space>", "<Plug>RDSendSelection")
    end,}
)
```

If I replace the global mapleader with a buffer one with
`vim.b.mapleader = " "` mapleader is bound to "\" even for files that are not R scripts.

So I am a bit lost on wether it is possible to have a mapleader for a specific filetype

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It happens because `vim.g.mapleader` is a global variable affecting all buffers once you set it.

You should use intead `vim.g.maplocalleader` and use `<LocalLeader>` for all the commands that you expect to run with your given filetype.

See docs with `:help localleader`

Comment: I am not sure this will help. The problem is that the mapleader clashes with the keymap for the filetype. I am not seeing how a localleader will solve this issue.

Comment: The reason `<localleader>` exists is for your especific use case. You want to have different "leaders" depending on your filetype. That's your use case, right? Althought you set the mapleader inside `nvim_create_autocmd`, it has no effect in functionality, even if you `:echo mapleader` it prints `\\` which might lead to confusion because it is not actually using it as <leader>.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation.

I guess my problem lies in the fact that I want ALL the mappings using `<leader>` to change with the filetype.

Now, wheter I use `<leader>` or `<localleader>` inside the `autocmd`, checking `:nmap` I see that mappings will use the default key  for the filetype for mappings that are configured in the `after/plugin` directory, and not the key defined in the filetype

So I would like to define the `<leader>` pretty early in the `init.lua`  and carry that into the plugin configs.